# Ephemeral messages always True on Pycord?

Tags: python, bots, pycord

This is related to a Discord bot using Pycord 2.4.1 on Python 3.9.
Starting these days, it started to respond to button interactions with ephemeral messages, but it is not supposed to. Default behavior is 'ephemeral=False', and I even tried to explicitly declare that on code. It was working just fine for long, and no changes were made on my side, it just started to behave like that. Does anyone have any idea why is that?

Sample code:

```py
 @discord.ui.button(label='Accept', emoji='', style=discord.ButtonStyle.primary, custom_id='Accept')
    async def accept_callback(self, button, inter):
        async with lock:
            srv = srv_switch(inter)
            loc = 'en' if inter.guild.preferred_locale.lower() != 'pt-br' else 'br'
            king = self.bot.get_guild(inter.guild.id).get_role(classes[srv]['contests'].get_king_role_id())
            chal = self.bot.get_guild(inter.guild.id).get_role(classes[srv]['contests'].get_chal_role_id())
            if king in inter.user.roles:
                if chal.members:
                    await inter.response.send_message(strings.text_chal_accept[loc].format(chal.members[0].mention),
                                                      view=Victory(self.bot))
                else:
                    await inter.response.send_message(strings.text_chal_issue[loc])
            else:
                await inter.response.send_message(strings.text_aint_king[loc].format(inter.user.display_name))
                pass
```

After clicking the "Accept" button, the response comes as ephemeral.

I tried explicitly declaring "ephemeral=False" on send_message function, to no avail.

Comment: Could you send a screenshot of what you're seeing as ephemeral?

Comment: I tried adding it to the question, but... "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." :/ [link to screenshot](https://postimg.cc/N91JHVm1)

Comment: It doesn't look like you explicitly set the ephemeral to false in the response for your sample code.

Comment: Because you don't need to, according to the documentation. I just mentioned I tried it, and it didn't help.

Comment: Can you send the relevant documentation that you're referring to

Comment: [Pycord documentation](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message)

Answer (score 0):

It took a while, but it started to work as it should without any changes on my side. I don't know why, but it seems to be solved.

Comment: Because this is not reproducible, it's likely that your post will be closed

Comment: Definitely, can I close it myself?

Comment: You can't but I'd just leave it as is because of question banning